# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\sin(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent (absolutely convergent or conditionally convergent), then
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n) $$
>   is also convergent.

Any hint? today I'm not at my best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to think about $(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n}\to 0$? This could be some motivation.

Comment: Could you please add a little more context?  Is this a true or false question?  Do you have any thoughts on whether or not it is true?

Comment: I'm sorry. Right, I actually don't now if this is true or not.

Comment: this should be chill for absolutely converging series, since $|\sin(n)|$ is bounded. for conditionally converging ones, a priori i'm scared that the signs might get weird, for example, if we had $\cos(\pi n)$ instead, and $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ we'd be in trouble...

Comment: Of course, absolutely convergent $\implies$ absolutely convergent. But convergent does not imply convergent (try $a_n=\sin(n)/n$).

Comment: @did: I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @sdcvvc Indeed. But the OP thinks otherwise since an answer is accepted, hence I will let things as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the series is absouletely convergent, the proof is fairly straightforward as we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| \geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n \sin(n)|
$$

as $ |\sin(n) | \leq 1 $ for all n. For conditionally convergent series, I'm not too sure on how it can be proven. Indeed, for a lot of conditionally convergent series, doing anything to the $a_n$ terms can cause the new series to not converge.

Comment: Thanks! that's actually my problem. When the series converges conditionally, is there any example of $a_n$ that makes the series $\sum a_n \sin(n)$ diverge?

Comment: @V. Galerkin: Did you see did's comment?

Comment: By the looks of it, did's suggestion (in the comments of your original post) of $a_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n} $ is such an example.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint**: Using the alternating series test we know that for each monotonically decreasing sequence $a_n$ with nonnegative $a_n$ and $a_n\to 0$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges.

Comment: Don't see why this is relevant.

Comment: @GEdgar: I thought about that fact that $|\sin(n)|\leq 1$ like Andrew mentioned this could be an "easier" example to simplify $\sin$ if you understand.

Comment: I think you meant an analogy: $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, while $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \cdot (-1)^n$ does not.